# react native android textinput it does not contain any id

Tags: react-native

I am still currently developing my simple calculator to know the basics of React Native and also researching online and the original react native documentation and I stumbled upon this problem.

my code:

```
                {/****** TEXT INPUT CONTAINER ******/}
                <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
                {/****** TEXT INPUT 1 ******/}
                <TextInput style={styles.textInput1}
                
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                placeholder = {" Enter 1st \n number \n here."}
                placeholderTextColor = '#66FCF1'
                keyboardType = 'number-pad'
                multiline = {true}
                returnKeyType = {"next"}
                onSubmitEditing={ this.secondInput.focus()}> //* This  will shift the focus to the next textinput *
                
                </TextInput>

                {/****** TEXT INPUT 2 ******/}
                <TextInput style={styles.textInput2}
                
                placeholder = {" Enter 2nd \n number \n here."}
                placeholderTextColor ='#EDF5E1'
                keyboardType = 'number-pad'
                multiline = {true}
                onSubmitEditing={ Keyboard.dismiss }> //* This will dismiss the keyboard once user submitted *
                </TextInput>
            </View>
```

I have 2 TextInputs in my code and it when the user enters the value on textinput1 the focus will be shifted to textinput2. I checked some questions here and answers and this is the closest and easiest path I saw to slowly grasp the basics of react native.

```
   onSubmitEditing={() =>{this.secondTextInput.focus(); }}
```

but I noticed that my secondInput doesn't have an id not a name to call. How do I do this? I checked the documentation online of textinput it does not contain any id not a name. I would be so glad if you can help me on this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the second textInput tag you have to add the following code. Then the first input will focus on this

```
<TextInput
    ref={(input) => { this.secondTextInput = input; }}
>
```

Just make sure you are calling the same name from first texInput which you given as the reference name inside the second textInput.

Comment: do I input in the first input onSubmitEditing = { input } ? Sorry if I came to ask you again I am just a little bit confused with this matter.

Comment: No you can just make a change, onSubmitEditing={() => { this.secondTextInput.focus(); }}

Comment: No need to add { input } inside onSubmitEditing you can use the above code as the onSubmitEditing for your first textInput.

Comment: thanks now I know how :) Sorry for asking you again man I am a total beginner on coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ref here. Try the below code.

```
<TextInput style={styles.textInput1}
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            placeholder = {" Enter 1st \n number \n here."}
            placeholderTextColor = '#66FCF1'
            keyboardType = 'number-pad'
            multiline = {true}
            returnKeyType = {"next"}
            onSubmitEditing={(event) => this._password._root.focus()}
            >
</TextInput>

            {/****** TEXT INPUT 2 ******/}
<TextInput style={styles.textInput2}
            getRef={(c) => this._password = c}
            placeholder = {" Enter 2nd \n number \n here."}
            placeholderTextColor ='#EDF5E1'
            keyboardType = 'number-pad'
            multiline = {true}
            onSubmitEditing={ Keyboard.dismiss }
            >
```

Answer (score 1):

{/****** TEXT INPUT 1 ******/}

```
<TextInput style={styles.textInput1}
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            placeholder = {" Enter 1st \n number \n here."}
            placeholderTextColor = '#66FCF1'
            keyboardType = 'number-pad'
            multiline = {true}
            returnKeyType = {"next"}
            onSubmitEditing={(event) => this.passwordTextInput.focus()} // focus on password textInput on submit 
            blurOnSubmit={false} //add this to prevent keyboard flickering
            >
</TextInput>
```

{/****** TEXT INPUT 2 ******/}

```
<TextInput style={styles.textInput2}
           ref={(r) => this.passwordTextInput = r} // initialize reference for your password txetInput
            placeholder = {" Enter 2nd \n number \n here."}
            placeholderTextColor ='#EDF5E1'
            keyboardType = 'number-pad'
            multiline = {true}
            onSubmitEditing={ Keyboard.dismiss }
            >
```